# Convert HDF5 file to other formats

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am having a few big files sets of HDF5 files and I am looking for an efficient way of converting the data in these files into XML, TXT or some other easily readable format. I tried working with the Python package (www.h5py.org), but I was not able to figure out any methods with which I can get this stuff done fast enough. I am not restricted to Python and can also code in Java, Scala or Matlab. Can someone give me some suggestions on how to proceed with this?

Thanks,

TM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `h5dump -o dset.asci -y -w 400 dset.h5`

- `-o dset.asci` specifies the output file
- `-y -w 400` specifies the dimension size multiplied by the number of positions and spaces needed to print each value. You should take a very large number here.
- `dset.h5` is of course the hdf5 file you want to convert

I think this is the easiest way to convert it to an ascii file, which you can import to excel or whatever you want. I did it a couple of times, and it worked for me. I got his information from [this](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/HDF5-FAQ.html#toexcel) website.

Answer (score 8):

Mathias711's method is the best direct way.  If you want to do it within python, then use pandas.HDFStore:

```
from pandas import HDFStore

store = HDFStore('inputFile.hd5')

store['table1Name'].to_csv('outputFileForTable1.csv')
```